# Getting exception on LocalDateTime.parse while using java8 with java11 works fine

Tags: java

Below code throws exception while executing in java8:

```
final DateTimeFormatter testDt2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
LocalDateTime.parse("20210718000000000", testDt2);
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20210718000000000' could not be parsed at index 0
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
> at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)

Same code works fine in java11.
Any work-around to get it done in java8?